# Browser's default CSS hides flash objects?

Tags: css, flash, drupal-7, embed

I have an embedded flash object in a Drupal-block, something like this:

```
<object classid="xxxxxx" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,40,0" height="320" width="160"><param name="quality" value="high" /><param name="movie" value="/sites/default/files/flash/xxxxxxx.swf" /><embed height="320" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" quality="high" src="/sites/default/files/flash/xxxxxxx.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="160"></embed></object>
```

A few days ago it disappeared misteriously. After some browsing in Firebug, I found out that it's nost likely caused by the following CSS-declaration:

```
img:-moz-suppressed, input:-moz-suppressed, object:-moz-suppressed, embed:-moz-suppressed, applet:-moz-suppressed {
    display: none !important;
    visibility: hidden !important;
}
```

It's coming from (as far as I understand) the default css of Firefox. I tried to set the "object" and "embed" tags visible but this declaration always override it. 
My questions are: Why is this default CSS-declaration come into effect now? It's not the first flash object I have embedded and they were visible so far. And how can I override it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you press "block images from this side" by accident? https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/:-moz-suppressed

Comment: I definitely didn't blocked anything from this site, but it was the situation though :S There were several blocked items in my AdBlock list - among them some objects from my site.
It's really weird because this flash object is blocked from other PC's too (I mean other people's PC's). I don't know how is it possible

Comment: I think this issue is finally got rid of: The swf file is actually called blahblah_banner.swf This pattern was blocked by AdBlock Plus. After renaming the file it can be seen with FireFox. I guess, there were a browser and/or ABp update in the last days and this caused the disappearance of the banner.